# UWP app webview Aurelia Polyfill throwing error

Tags: uwp, polyfills, aurelia

Currently running a webview from a UWP app and getting errors saying "Unhandled Promise rejection: Unspecified error" coming from Aurelia's polyfill.js file when I try and run the polyfill script in index.html.

This has only been an issue as of recently since the new Windows 10 update

Because the polyfill fails, the page fails to load

Tried including another polyfill library called polyfill.io but it continued to fail

I simply run this in index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="#####" aurelia-app="main">
        <div class="loading">
          <div class="cloud"></div>
        </div>

      <script src="{{####}}/dist/vendor-bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="{{####}}/dist/polyfill-bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="{{####}}/dist/app-bundle.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here is the error I get in the UWP webview

```
polyfill-bundle.js (1,71003)

[object Error]: {description: "Unspecified error.", message: "Unspecified error.", number: -2147467259, 
stack: "Error: Unspecified error. at Anonymous function 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:54:39348) at Anonymous function 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:93:664043) at Array.prototype.forEach (native code) at a.PLATFORM.eachModule 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:93:663974) at e.get 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:54:39233) at e.prototype.load 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:93:746777) at Anonymous function 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:93:4153532) at Array.prototype.map (native code) at l 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:93:4153479) at Anonymous function 
(#####/dist/vendor-bundle.js:93:4169836)"}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, your polyfill script is requesting permission.

WebView defaults to deny permission requests, but you can allow permission requests by listening to the `WebView.PermissionRequested` event.

```cs
private void WebView_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Although I do see a permission denied when diving deeper into the log statements, I added 


`private void ctlBrowser_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)            
        {        
            args.PermissionRequest.Allow();         
        }`          
and it never gets fired @richardzhang

Comment: Hi, you can try to open the page in the Edge UWP browser. then, can you provide a minimal runnable demo for us to test?